# Golang App-engine OAuth Authorization

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-oauth

I am implementing an app-engine webapp written in Go that needs user authentication *and* authorization to access some user data on Google's APIs.

Do I still need to use the goauth2 and gorilla packages to implement authorization or is there some functionality in the "appengine" and "appengine/user" packages that implements Oauthorization natively for app-engine apps? I do not mind going ahead with goauth2, but if there is a better way...

Comment: For me the best way is don't use any library, and just form the two Oauth URLs by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "appengine/user" package for authentication with OAuth but I'm a fraid that you must implement authorization yourself.
For OAuth authentication with "appengine/user" package, see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/oauth/#Go_OAuth_and_App_Engine

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from the [OAuth for Go Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/oauth/) on the [Google App Engine Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/) site:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "appengine"
    "appengine/user"
)

func welcome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u, err := user.CurrentOAuth(c, "")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "OAuth Authorization header required", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
    if !u.Admin {
        http.Error(w, "Admin login only", http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, `Welcome, admin user %s!`, u)
}
```

It looks like `appengine/user` has the function [`user.CurrentOAuth()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/reference#CurrentOAuth) to provide authentication functionality.

For authorization, there's an example using OpenID [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/).

There is a caveat; The documentation states:

> *Note that using OAuth to identify your users is completely orthogonal to the standard user authentication modes. For example, pages marked with login: required or login: admin will refuse to load if the user is only authenticated via OAuth.*

Full Go GAE reference available [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/users/reference).